# Regex - Find from second occurrence till second last occurrence

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I'm trying to match everything between first and last occurrence with Javascript's .match() or .replace() function. I will therefore be using regex to find what I need to remove. Content will be different with many lines and other characters, but this is just an example.

```
[quote=Person 1]
[quote=Person 2]
[quote=Person 3]
Person 3
[/quote]
Person 2
[/quote]
Person 1
[/quote]
```

I need to match and remove everything from second occurrence **[quote=Person 2]** till second last **[/quote]**

With that said, it should output this in the end:

```
[quote=Person 1]
Person 1
[/quote]
```

You can match the quote tags like this

```
\[quote(.*?)\]
```

and the end quote tag like this

```
\[\/quote\]
```

Comment: `str.split('[quote=Person 2]').shift()+str.split('[/quote]').filter(function(n) {return n.trim().length}).pop()`

Comment: JSfiddle that, please. Use this as example: http://jsfiddle.net/wQ4Fu/

Comment: Are you talking to me? If so, strings are immutable -> http://jsfiddle.net/wQ4Fu/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go (where x is the above example text):

```
var newx = x.replace(/^(\[quote=(?:(?!\[quote=)[\s\S]*?))\[quote=[\s\S]+\[\/quote\]\s*([\s\S]+?\[\/quote\]\s*)$/g, "$1$2")
```

This produces:

```
[quote=Person 1]
Person 1
[/quote]
```

Note that `x.replace()` doesn't change the contents of `x` -- you have to do an assignment like `var newx = x.replace(...);` or `x = x.replace(...)` to store the modified string.

Comment: @LemvigKiggeren -- it works as I wrote it. `.replace()` doesn't do an assignment.  So, if you do `x.replace(...)`, then echo `x`, you get the original value.  I have tweaked my answer to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

use this pattern `(\[quote=([^\]]+)\])[\s\S]+(?=\s\2)` and replace with `$1` [Demo](http://regex101.com/r/wH0jW2)